# devise edit form with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, devise

In my edit view, I want to apply bootstrap. However, when replacing...

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name), html: { method: :put }) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row form-group">
          <div class="col-md-4"><%= f.label :username %></div>
          <div class="col-md-8"><%= f.text_field :username %></div>
        </div>
```

with this...

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="username">Username</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username" value="<%= f.text_field :username %>"> 
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I get this as output [image]

I have tried many alternatives to include erb but don't understand the issue. How should I include the field in my edit forms?

Comment: remove whole input tag line and put simple <%= f.text_field :username %>

Comment: and then add class, placeholder there... oh my mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do all the things with rails.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :username %>
        <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Username" %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For more detail Please visit this link

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/text_field

If you want to use add-on you can as below

```
<div class='input-group' >
          <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Username" %>
          <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon2">@example.com</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Agree and Learning am newby

Comment: No problem, but if you satisfied with my answer please up vote this ans.

Comment: got a question related: how to add the bootstrap class input-group-addon ? the class I know,  not the sign for e.g. email @

Comment: Actually, i can't understand your question. can you please tell me in brief.

Comment: to the same field, besides the form-control class, I want to put an input-group-addon from bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-basic)

Comment: go that in place; can do without the id btw

Comment: why does <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Username" %> not work in the show action? I need to put it in a div. Would prefer not to.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116199/discussion-between-hardik-upadhyay-and-dimitri-de-ruiter).

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="sr-only" for="username">Username</label>
        <%= f.text_field :username, class: "form-control", placeholder: "Username" %>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a gem called `simple_form`, it's made by the creators of Devise and works nicely with Bootstrap. It also has nice validation errors.

https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form

Here's an example:

```
= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f|
      .form-inputs
        = f.input :email, required: false, autofocus: true, placeholder: 'Email'
        = f.input :password, required: false, placeholder: 'Password'
        = f.input :remember_me, as: :boolean, label: 'Remember Me' if devise_mapping.rememberable?
      .form-actions
        = f.button :submit, 'Sign in', class: 'btn-block btn-success'
      %br
      = link_to 'Forgot your password?', new_user_password_path
```

The code above will automatically add any bootstrap classes and labels...etc

Comment: quick view looks promissing